# Sublime - Remove .cache files from search results

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use the `command-shift-f` function a lot in sublime to grep my repository. However, there's always long, minified `.cache` files that show up which I wouldn't ever want to change since they're automatically generated.

Is there a way to stop sublime from searching or hide search results of those `.cache` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the Preferences menu -> Settings, you will find this in the Default `Preferences.sublime-preferences` file on the left:

```
// These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
// Goto Anything or Find in Files
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

you can simply copy this to your user preferences on the right, and add `, "*.cache`"`before the`]`and`.cache` files will no longer be searched because they will be treated as if they are binary files not worth searching.